# Enable header module on OS X server

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost, https, mac-osx-server

I have been using OS X Server for some time now and find that any attempt I make to manually edit the apache config files is somehow thwarted. I am using server 4.1 on yosemite 10.10.3 (all up to date) and the config file im editing is `/library/server/web/config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf`

I have made sure that the mod_headers.so module is not commented out, and have added the following lines to the config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to check the header with `curl -I`, there is no HSTS to be seen.

If anyone can help me to get HSTS set up on OS X Server, or offer insight into what I am doing wrong in general when trying to edit the config files, I would appreciate it immensely. I have tried to configure other modules in the past, such as compression or rewrite, with similar results.

Comment: Taking in mind you are setting it in a virtual host, are you sure you are hitting with curl the right VirtualHost?

Comment: Yes, that I'm sure of.

Comment: I believe I figured out how to make changes to my server configuration - there is a directive in the apache config - `# Certain generated config files, such as migrated forward proxy configs from SnowLeopard
IncludeOptional /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/*.conf` - I tried putting a file with just the three lines above in the other folder and naming it `hsts.conf` - it made my entire site inaccessible, which is not good, but at least i know how to change the configuration now. Does anyone have any idea how to successfully incorporate this header?